# Reg File For Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

Is there any registry file to disable changing time by users in windows xp?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a registry setting for this, but in my mind the correct way to do this is to  join the useraccount to Users group and remove it from Administrators or Power Users -groups.

For example at Command prompt (DOS-window) you can do this:
Check useraccount's groups and check group's menbers:

```
    net user MyUser 
    net localgroup Users
```

Add useraccount to local group:

```
    net localgroup Users MyUser /add
```

Remove useraccount from local group

```
    net localgroup Administrators MyUser /delete
```

When in Active Directory (=Domain) environment this is a bit more complicated, but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `gpedit.msc`(Start > Run). Go to 'Computer Configuration/Windows Settings/Security Settings/Local Policies/Users Rights Assignments'.
In the right-hand window, double click on 'Change the system time'.
Disable it.

This only works when your user is not a local admin. When the computer is part of a domain, it's easier to push a GPO.